# how to change background image periodically in android

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image, android-asynctask

in my app in android, i need change background image in image view on 10 seconds once. so that i call a Async Task within a run method. when I execute the app  it crashes. 
It gives the   `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()` Exception to me.

I know I have to use Thread, but I do not know how to do so properly. Please help me.

This is my code sample:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        .................
    new Thread() 
    {
        public void run() 
        {
            while(true){
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            count = count + 1;

            new ImageChange().execute();
          }
        }       
    }.start();  

} // OnCreate End


class ImageChange extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> 
{       
    protected void onPreExecute() { 

    }   
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        iv1.setImageBitmap(b1);
        iv2.setImageBitmap(b2);
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        switch(count){

            case 1:            


                b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f1.getAbsolutePath());
                b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f2.getAbsolutePath());    
            break;  
            case 2:


                b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f2.getAbsolutePath());
                b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f1.getAbsolutePath());

            break;      
            default :
                count = 0;      
                b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f1.getAbsolutePath());
                b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f2.getAbsolutePath());

            break;    
        }

     return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, beforer I look into your problem, there are several things that strike me: (1) no need to set b1 and b2 to null before setting them to something else, that has no special effect. (2) The goodf way to name a class in Java is to use CamelCase: name it ImageChange instead of imagechange

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the AsyncTask from a worker Thread. This way it has no access to the UI thread. You probably should consider using a Handler.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the problem is that you must execute the `ImageChange.doInBackground()` method in the UI thread. Try to change your code like this:

```
class ImageChange extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    Activity act;

    public ImageChange(Activity act) {
        this.act = act;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        iv1.setImageBitmap(b1);
        iv2.setImageBitmap(b2);
    }
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        switch(count) {
            case 1:            
                helperMethod(f1.getAbsolutePath(), f2.getAbsolutePath());
            break;  
            case 2:
                helperMethod(f2.getAbsolutePath(), f1.getAbsolutePath());
            break;      
            default :
                count = 0;      
                helperMethod(f1.getAbsolutePath(), f2.getAbsolutePath());
            break;    
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void helperMethod(String a, String b) {
        act.runOnUIThread(new Runable() {
            public void run() {
                b1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(a);
                b2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(b);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that you must pass an Activity to the ImageChange class constructor. It means that you have to call the asyncTask in this way:

```
new ImageChange(this).execute();
```

Also consider the possibility of using the class [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html)

EDIT: Change the Activity part of your code with this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
        .................

    new ImageChange().execute();

} // OnCreate End
```

And add the `while(true)` to the ImageChange class:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        while(true) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            count = count + 1;

            switch(count) {
                ...    
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

EDIT2: You can solve the problem about onPostExecute inserting the code that must be execute after each iteration inside the while loop:

```
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        while(true) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            count = count + 1;

            switch(count) {
                ...    
            }
            act.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    iv1.setImageBitmap(b1);
                    iv2.setImageBitmap(b2);
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The code you insert inside the while loop must run in the UI thread; in fact, every onPostExecute method of the AsyncTask class runs on UI thread.

Comment: See the EDIT part of my answer

Comment: thanks, but the PostExecute method will be called when doInBackground is completed. as your logic doInBackground never be completed. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by using Handler Thread.